# Getting undefined error in jquery gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am still a beginner so bear with me. I am trying to write an image gallery with jquery. I am getting an undefined error at :
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

Here is my js code:

```
$(function(){
    var slideIndex = 1;
 $('.demo').on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var o = $(this).attr("data-slide");
        showSlides(slideIndex = o);
        console.log(o);
    });

$('.arrow').on('click', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var g = $(this).attr('data-move');
      showSlides(slideIndex += g);
  });

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = $(".mySlides");
    var dots = $(".demo");
    var captionText = $("#caption");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    console.log(slides[slideIndex-1]);
    console.log(slideIndex);
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
  }
});
```

Here is a codepen of the whole code with placeholder, somehow the big picture doesnt work, it does work on my localhost:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/prdRXM

Comment: This most likely means no object/data exists in the `slides` array at the index you are providing. Try running your code with a debugger in function and you will be able to see where the undefined error is occurring and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... Since you use jQuery to get the images collection, better keep on using jQuery to select one.

You are using the pure JavaScript bracket `[]` array syntax when `.eq()` method is more efficient.

The index to use with `.eq()` is zero based... Fits perfectly with the element collection you have. So I removed all `-1` from slideIndex.

Then, instead of looping the collections to hide them, just apply `.hide()` on the whole thing (more efficient again... And actually working).

Another issue was about the values from the data attributes being text instead of integer. I used `parseInt()` a couple places.

So here is you code debugged... I left all `console.log()` I used:

```
console.clear();

$(function(){
  var slideIndex = 0;
  $('.demo').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var o = parseInt($(this).attr("data-slide"));
    slideIndex = o;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    console.log("o: "+o+" type: "+typeof(o));
  });

  $('.arrow').on('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var g = parseInt($(this).attr('data-move'));
    console.log($(this).attr('data-move'));
    console.log("g in arrow: "+g+" Type: "+typeof(g));
    slideIndex += g;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
  });

  /*        // Moved lower... "showSlides" is not defined yet here.
  function plusSlides(n) {
    slideIndex += parseInt(n);
    showSlides(slideIndex);
  }
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  */

  function showSlides(n) {
    console.log("n in showslide: "+n+" Type: "+typeof(n));

    //var i;
    var slides = $(".mySlides");
    var dots = $(".demo");
    var captionText = $("#caption");

    if (n > slides.length-1) {slideIndex = 0}
    if (n < 0) {slideIndex = slides.length-1}

    // Why  loops?
    /*
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    */

    // This works great instead of loops
    slides.hide();
    dots.hide();

    console.log(slides.eq(slideIndex));
    console.log(slideIndex);


    //slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    //dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    slides.eq(slideIndex).show().addClass("active");

    //captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    captionText.html(dots.eq(slideIndex).attr("alt"));
  }

  function plusSlides(n) {
  console.log("n in plusslide: "+n+" Type: "+typeof(n));
    slideIndex += parseInt(n);
    showSlides(slideIndex);
  }
  showSlides(slideIndex);
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/NvwprV?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks but this didn't do the job, now I am getting a NaN Error on top of the other.

Comment: I'm working on it... There is a couple subtile error... Like `data-mvove="1"` on the right arrow.... Hold on.